Acceleration in spring-mass system
So the original question is to find the maximum elongation in the spring:
https://imgur.com/a/hI4o3HH

The solution used $F_{net}=ma$ for both the masses.But,they assumed same acceleration for both of them.When the spring is maximum elongated,the blocks have relative velocity 0, I.e their velocities are equal,and  not their accelerations,right?
Relative velocity being 0 does not imply relative acceleration is also zero.
So why is the acceleration for both the masses equal?

Do you agree the accelerations would be the same if there were no spring and just a massless string?

Yes.Because it will be inextensible

When the spring is maximally elongated, it will no longer extend and just act like an inextensible string. At this moment, both blocks will act as though they are connected by a massless, inextensible string and hence, must face the same acceleration (assuming both the string and spring are massless in the figure).
(Just as an aside, I would suggest being careful about the difference between speed and velocity. The blocks do have relative velocity, since velocity is a directional quantity. One block moves up and the other moves down. Its possible to have zero relative speed but non-zero relative velocity.)

What will happen after they achieve the common acceleration?Won't they change the acceleration afterwards?Also,when do the objects achieve the maximum distance from each other?when their relative velocity is zero or relative speed is zero?

If the string+spring setup is long enough, after transient behaviour dies down, the stable configuration for the system will be the spring extended to whatever length is necessary so that the entire system can move with a common acceleration (think why, based on the spring's motion if this isn't true). When relative speed towards each other is zero, objects will maintain their distance from each other.

You have to assume that the diagram shows the masses undergoing constant acceleration and the spring extension is constant.
Further assumptions are that the strings and massless and inextensible, the spring is massless but obeys Hooke's law, and there is no friction anywhere.
Suppose the $15\,\rm kg$ imposes a downward force $T$ on the bottom left-hand string then the bottom left-hand string must impose an upward force $T$ on the $15\,\rm kg$ mass (N3L).
Because the string is massless, the upward force on the bottom left-hand string due to the spring must be $T$ and this results in a downward force on spring due to the bottom left-hand string $T$ (N3L).
Because the spring is massless, the upward force on the spring due to the top left-hand string must be $T$ and this results in a downward force on top left-hand string due to the spring $T$ (N3L).
As the string is massless, all the pulley does is transmit the force $T$ as an upward force on the $5\,\rm kg$ mass, with the $5\,\rm kg$ mass exerting a force $T$ on the bottom of the right-hand string (N3L).
In essence because the spring is massless forces exerted by the strings at each end of the spring must be equal in magnitude and because of the assumption that the length of the spring is constant which is also true of the strings that means that the acceleration of the two masses must be the same.
Imposing initial conditions like the two masses start from rest, the spring starts at its unextended length, etc, and trying to figure out how the final state is reached is going to lead to questions with difficult/impossible answers due to the non-physical nature of problem.
